# How to drop old commits in git

Tags: git

Sometimes bad people push file in a SCM that have nothing to do here:

- Test reports
- Compiled file
- Other SCM file
- Cache

So git repositories (works also with SVN) can become fat, very fat. How can we make them lose this useless fat ? I've a git repo which is bigger than 1 GB, how can I keep the last 500 hundreds commits and drop the other useless data ?

I've read about using squashing but since this repo is used by a team I guess it's not the right way.

Answer (score 0):

remove branches/tags that refer to the commit and then use git-gc